Sargability of RIGHT/LEFT in SQL
How can I make the LEFT and RIGHT functions in SQL sargable?
My T-SQL Lint (v1.15.3.0) yields an error on the following code:
SELECT DISTINCT B.BookID
FROM #Books B
WHERE RIGHT(B.[Name], 10) = '-mypostfix';

error non-sargable : Performing functions on filter clauses 
or join predicates can cause performance problems.

I used a RIGHT function to avoid a wildcard at the beginning of my string (e.g. LIKE %-mypostfix), which seems like it would be less performant. However, after some research, I found that SQL can leverage its search index when using a wildcard. LEFT and RIGHT force the database to look through every row. Nonetheless, I am convinced that RIGHT ought to be faster, especially for somewhat long strings.
Would I really need to use the wildcard strategy to avoid this linter error?

"I am convinced that RIGHT ought to be faster" why? Neither can use an index, they both have to examine every row. The exact performance difference of a substring check vs using LIKE is going to be very small vs the cost of examining every row. The only option you have is to make a computed column of the RIGHT calculation and index that.

I agree. At first, I thought a wildcard matching algorithm would be O(n*m) whereas RIGHT would be O(n). In reality, the performance difference across 48k records is negligible.

No why would it be O(n*m)? It's perfectly capable of detecting that there is no trailing wildcard and therefore it can search back from the end of the text.

You can't for RIGHT; indexes store the values in an order, so when you want to search for values which end with specific characters then the index can't be used as that's not the order the index is in.
Most likely the need to use RIGHT is a design flaw, and you are storing multiple different values in that column, rather than a single one. You probably should be using 2 (or more) columns for the separate values. Perhaps you should have a bit column named mypostfix, or you need varchar column that can store the value 'mypostfix'. You know you're requirements better than us to know which is correct
For LEFT, just use LIKE as trailing wildcards are SARGable:
SELECT <Your Columns>
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE @SearchValue +'%';


If right searches are very common on a column, one could create an index on REVERSE(YourColumn) and write the queries as WHERE REVERSE(YourColumn) LIKE REVERSE(@SearchValue) +'%', but you are right, this smells like a design flaw. A very good point.

Great points. Ironically, my boss admitted when I began this task that this originates from a design flaw in our DB. Funny that you spotted it!

A few years back I added an extra column with the reversed value, just to index it and searches became blazing fast.
